# Parsing array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to parse an array of objects, so I would end up with an array of all elements containing 'text' of 'ild'.

Here is a sample array:

```
public data: any[] = [
  {
    treeViewKey:0,
    id: 1,
    text: 'Root Node 1'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:1,
    id: 2,
    text: 'Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:1_0,
    id: 3,
    parentId: 2,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:1_1,
    id: 4,
    parentId: 2,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:1_2_0,
    id: 5,
    parentId: 4,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }
];
```

I should end up with 3 elements. What would be the best method to achieve that in javascript or typescript?

The final result should be:

```
      [
    {
    treeViewKey:1_0,
    id: 3,
    parentId: 2,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:1_1,
    id: 4,
    parentId: 2,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:1_2_0,
    id: 5,
    parentId: 4,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. what have you tried?

Comment: what does "text of ild" mean?

Comment: 'text' is a property, and 'ild' is a text used for searching. As an example 'Child node...' contains word 'ild'

Comment: `1_0` is not valid JavaScript. Is that actually a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for all the children, you have a better property to get them.

That's the `parentId`. If the `parentId` is specified, then they are children.

So filter the data input looking for the ones with `parentId` property specified.

Below there is also the case looking for 'ild' in text as you asked.

```js
const data = [
  {
    treeViewKey:0,
    id: 1,
    text: 'Root Node 1'
  }, 
  {
    treeViewKey:1,
    id: 2,
    text: 'Root Node 2'
  }, 
  {
    treeViewKey:'1_0',
    id: 3,
    parentId: 2,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:'1_1',
    id: 4,
    parentId: 2,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }, {
    treeViewKey:'1_2_0',
    id: 5,
    parentId: 4,
    text: 'Child node of Root Node 2'
  }
];

// filter the elements with parentId property
console.log(data.filter(el => el.parentId));
// filter the elements with 'ild' string in text property
console.log(data.filter(el => el.text.includes('ild')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
const elements = data.filter(item => item.parentId);
```